# Query totals for each week from beginning of the year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Hi I have a table like below :

```
Item    Date    Quantity
1   1/1/2015    34
1   1/1/2015    34
1   1/2/2015    23
1   7/1/2015    12
1   6/25/2015   4
1   1/1/2015    1
2   1/1/2015    53
2   1/2/2015    42
2   7/1/2015    12
2   6/25/2015   66
```

I want to run a query to see what the quantity is for an item for each week from the beginning of the year. Is there a way I can do it ?

```
Output :
Item WeekendDate Quantity 
1         01/03/2015   92
```

This is how far I got and I don't know how I can go forward :

```
select Item, Date, Sum(Quantity) from Table T 
group by Item, Date
```

Comment: `select Item, Date, Sum(Quantity) from Table T 
group by Item, Date WITH ROLLUP`

Comment: and newer `select Item, Date, Sum(Quantity) from Table T group by ROLLUP ( Item, Date)` of coure before you need to reduce granularity of date to one week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (Item INT, [Date] DATE, Quantity INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(1   ,'1/1/2015',    34),
(1   ,'1/1/2015',    34),
(1   ,'1/2/2015',    23),
(1   ,'7/1/2015',    12),
(1   ,'6/25/2015',   4),
(1   ,'1/1/2015',    1),
(2   ,'1/1/2015',    53),
(2   ,'1/2/2015',    42),
(2   ,'7/1/2015',    12),
(2   ,'6/25/2015',   66)
```

### Query

```
SELECT Item
     ,DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [Date]), CAST([Date] AS DATE)) Weekend
     ,SUM(Quantity) Week_Total
FROM @TABLE
GROUP BY Item, DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [Date]), CAST([Date] AS DATE))
```

### Result

```
╔══════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ Item ║  Weekend   ║ Week_Total ║
╠══════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║    1 ║ 2015-01-03 ║         92 ║
║    2 ║ 2015-01-03 ║         95 ║
║    1 ║ 2015-06-27 ║          4 ║
║    2 ║ 2015-06-27 ║         66 ║
║    1 ║ 2015-07-04 ║         12 ║
║    2 ║ 2015-07-04 ║         12 ║
╚══════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Be careful with `DATEPART` function. "When datepart is week (wk, ww) or weekday (dw), the return value depends on the value that is set by using `SET DATEFIRST`."

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more variant to "truncate/round" the date to one week precision.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (Item INT, dt DATE, Quantity INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(1   ,'2015-01-01',    34),
(1   ,'2015-01-01',    34),
(1   ,'2015-01-02',    23),
(1   ,'2015-07-01',    12),
(1   ,'2015-06-25',     4),
(1   ,'2015-01-01',     1),
(2   ,'2015-01-01',    53),
(2   ,'2015-01-02',    42),
(2   ,'2015-07-01',    12),
(2   ,'2015-06-25',    66);

SELECT
    Item
    ,DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, '20150103', dt), '20150103') AS Weekend
    ,SUM(Quantity) Week_Total
FROM @TABLE
GROUP BY
    Item
    ,DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, '20150103', dt), '20150103')
```

**result**

```
Item     Weekend                    Week_Total
1        2015-01-03 00:00:00.000    92
2        2015-01-03 00:00:00.000    95
1        2015-06-27 00:00:00.000    4
2        2015-06-27 00:00:00.000    66
1        2015-07-04 00:00:00.000    12
2        2015-07-04 00:00:00.000    12
```

In this method it may be easier to pick the date that is the start/end of the week. Just put another date in the formula instead of `20150103`. In some countries week starts from Monday, not Sunday. Also, this method doesn't depend on the server settings that affect results of [`DATEPART`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function.

> When datepart is week (wk, ww) or weekday (dw), the return value
>   depends on the value that is set by using SET DATEFIRST.